# force command-line-argument to wrap in quotes on qmake

Tags: windows, qt, copy, qmake

I have a file called libstdc++-6.dll that Windows' copy program is returning

> system cannot find the file specified

When called from `qmake` without quotes. If I wrap that file name with quotes the `copy` ran just fine in `cmd`. So, how can I force a particular command-line argument within Qt wrap with quotes? I tried `$$quote($${FILE})` but it fail in the same way.

```
EXTRA_BINFILES += \
    $${QTDIR}\bin\libstdc++-6.dll \
    $${QTDIR}\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll

    for(FILE,EXTRA_BINFILES) {
        QMAKE_PRE_LINK += $$quote($${QMAKE_COPY} $$quote($${FILE}) $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\n\t))
    }
```

EDIT:

I tried this too `$$quote($${QTDIR}\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll)` but can't see the being quoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the proper way to do it but  `"\"$${FILE}\""` was the only thing which worked for me